Proof : $A-(B\cup C)= A\cap B^C\cap C^C $
Is the following proof sufficient to prove that for three sets $A,B,C, A-(B\cup C)= A\cap B^C\cap C^C $? Or do I need to prove in some other way that for some $a\in A \iff a\in A-(B\cup C) \land a\in A\cap B^C\cap C^C $ ?
Let A,B,C be subsets of $S$ , then : $$A-(B \cup C)=A\cap(B\cup C)^C=A\cap B^C \cap C^C$$
The second step comes from the fact that for 2 sets $X,Y$ $, X-Y=X\cap Y^C$

It depends on what you have already proved. From my experience in undergrad, my professors allowed me to use other results in my proof only if I had proved them previously (in class or on a homework assignment). As long as you cite the reasoning for both steps, I think you would be safe (but that's just from my experiences).

I cannot make much sense from the line $a \in A \iff \dots $, I assume you mean $a \in A - (B \cup C) \iff a \in A \cap B^c \cap C^c$. But you will not need to work with specific elements. In your proof, I think your reasoning is fine, if maybe somewhat minimalistic. You should maybe also mention that/why $(B \cup C)^c = B^c \cap C^c$.

Your proof relies on three facts: $$X - Y = X\cap Y^c\(X \cup Y)^c = X^c \cap Y^c\X\cap (Y \cap Z) = (X \cap Y) \cap Z$$(The third is what allows you to write the RH side with no parentheses, since the two possible interpretations give the same result.) I agree with June Richardson: if all three have already been shown, by you or as part of the class, then your proof is fine. But if there is one that you cannot trace down, then you will need to justify it as part of your proofe.
